# Is there a way to access the main graphics context of the HTML page?

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas, framebuffer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using HTML5/Canvas/Javascript to take screenshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-screenshots)

Is there a way to copy the main graphics context of the HTML page into a canvas?

From Javascript, I'd like to grab a "screen shot" of the current visible HTML page and copy it to a thumbnail image or canvas. (Not from a separate "screen capture" app, but from within the javascript page itself)

Comment: take a look at this: http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/demos/content/thumbnail is this what you wanted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it.
But If you using google chrome you can write a chrome extension, this give you new javascript functions for capturing images, for example:

```
chrome.tab.captureVisibleTab( ....)
```

For example, you can check the source code Webpage Screenshot Extesnion:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/webpage-webcam-screenshot/ckibcdccnfeookdmbahgiakhnjcddpki

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I would agree that this is a duplicate - but it did not come up as a possible match when I entered the question, so I did not see it. I thank you for the references to tools that appear very interesting - unfortunately, won't quite meet my needs. I was hoping there might be some low-level DOM element that contained the actual bitmap representation of the entire rendered page that I could easily access. Since we actually own the browser on our primary device, we'll probably look into adding a hook to get at the HTML engine's frame buffer.